# How do you stage Camel K integrations?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, staging, kubernetes-operator, apache-camel-k

If you are using Camel K with its operator on Kubernetes or OpenShift, how do you implement staging? Do I have to build the image for every stage - e.g. three times for test, ua and production? Or is there another way to deploy the once built image with the Camel K operator on further stages?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `Integration` tested and staged, you can get the resulting `IntegrationKit` image as a reference for your production `Integration`, ie:

```
$ k get integrationkit
NAME                       PHASE   TYPE       IMAGE
kit-c82emh1c11s7ki7ijq0g   Ready   platform   10.108.177.66/default/camel-k-kit-c82emh1c11s7ki7ijq0g@sha256:10cd5eea251bc7992f08c9d96fc61d004ed220fbec7fefa20321e0956172a737

$ kamel run Sample.java -t container.image=10.108.177.66/default/camel-k-kit-c82emh1c11s7ki7ijq0g@sha256:10cd5eea251bc7992f08c9d96fc61d004ed220fbec7fefa20321e0956172a737 --dev
```